# From a pandas dataframe containing net exports between any two countries, how can I get second dataframe containing net exports for each country?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` containing net exports between any two countries in column `From` and `To` respectively.

`df.to_dict()` returns

```
{'From': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'},
 'To': {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'A'},
 'Net exports': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5}}
```

It looks as follows:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6BRe.png

I want to get a second dataframe `df2` which shows net trade per country.
It means, if a country is in `From` column in `df`, its value needs to be added.
If the country is in `To` column in `df`, its value needs to be subtracted.

It should look something as shown:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1xrE.png

For example,
in `df`, A to B is 3, A to C is 6 and D to A is 5. Hence, the value of A in `df2` is 3+6-5 = 4.

Note, sometimes some countries may not appear in both From and To columns in `df`.
To get list of all countries in both columns, I could use

```
all_countries = list(set(df["From"]).union(set(df["To"])))
all_countries
```

However, what would be the process to proceed to the next step to get `df2` from `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) on both From and To, [`subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.subtract.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
out = (df
   .groupby('From')['Net exports'].sum()
   .sub(df.groupby('To')['Net exports'].sum())
   .rename_axis('Countries').reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Countries  Net exports
0         A            4
1         B           -1
2         C           -6
3         D            3
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

A possible solution, which is based on [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) without any grouping:

```
(pd.DataFrame({x: z, y: -z} for x, y, z in zip(*[df[col] for col in df])).sum()
 .reset_index(name='Net exports').rename(columns={'index': 'Countries'}))
```

---

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, we can [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframe with itself, identifying the duplicated ([`pandas.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)), multiplying by `-1` the duplicated, and finally using [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
d = pd.concat([df, df.assign(From = df['To'])])
d.loc[d.index.duplicated(), 'Net exports'] *= -1
(d.drop('To', axis=1).rename(columns={'From': 'Countries'})
 .groupby('Countries', as_index=False).sum())
```

Shorter, more elegant and faster is the solution proposed by @mozway (to whom I thank) in a comment below:

```
(pd.concat([df.set_index('From')['Net exports'],
            df.set_index('To')['Net exports'].mul(-1)])
 .groupby(level=0).sum().rename_axis('Countries').reset_index())
```

---

**Solution 3**

Another possible solution, which splits the dataframe by columns `From` and `To`, multiplies by `-1` the `Net exports` column of the second dataframe, vertically stacks the dataframes as `numpy` arrays ([`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)), creates a new dataframe from the stacked `numpy` arrays, and finally uses [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) to get the wanted result:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack([df.iloc[:,[0,2]].values, df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
               .assign(**{'Net exports': -df.iloc[:,2].values})]), 
    columns=['Countries','Net exports'])
 .groupby('Countries', as_index=False).sum())
```

---

**Output**

```
  Countries Net exports
0         A           4
1         B          -1
2         C          -6
3         D           3
```

Comment: I like the `concat` approach, but I would rather use: `pd.concat([df.set_index('From')['Net exports'], df.set_index('To')['Net exports'].mul(-1)]).groupby(level=0).sum().rename_axis('Countries').reset_index()`

Comment: Indeed, that is a better, more elegant and faster solution, @mozway! Thanks for sharing it with me! (I have edit my answer with that.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
import pandas as pd

```
ab=pd.DataFrame({'From': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'},
 'To': {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'A'},
 'Net exports': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5}})
exports=ab.groupby(['From'])['Net exports'].sum().reset_index() #group by from column to get exports 
exports=exports.rename(columns={'Net exports':'exports'})       #renaming column
imports=ab.groupby(['To'])['Net exports'].sum().reset_index() #group by To column to get imports
imports=imports.rename(columns={'Net exports':'imports'})
final=exports.merge(imports,left_on=['From'],right_on=['To'],how='outer') #outer merge on exports and imports dataframe to get all values from both dfs
final['net export']=final['exports']-final['imports'] # get final number by deducting the two
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
tmp = df1.melt('Net exports', value_name='Countries')
out = tmp['Net exports'].mul(tmp['variable'].map({'From':1, 'To':-1}))\
                        .groupby(tmp['Countries']).sum().reset_index(name='Net exports')
```

out

```
    Countries   Net exports
0   A           4 
1   B           -1
2   C           -6
3   D           3
```